# Height issue with Typography and Grid inn Material-UI

Tags: material-ui

I get height issue when using typography inside Grid, so basically, there is an unexpected space between last item and second item.

here is my code

```
    <Grid container direction="column" spacing={2}>
      <Grid item>
        <Typography variant="h1">Test</Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Grid container alignItems="center" style={{ border: '1px solid red' }}>
          <Grid item xs={2}>
            <Typography variant="body1">Testing Column 1</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={4}>
            <Typography variant="body1">Testing Column 1</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6}>
            <Typography variant="body1">Testing Column 1</Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>Issue Here</Grid>
    </Grid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your last `Grid` is outside the parent `Grid Group`, Bring it inside the group will solve the issue**

```
<Grid container direction="column" spacing={2}>
  <Grid item>
    <Typography variant="h1">Test</Typography>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item>
    <Grid container alignItems="center" style={{ border: "1px solid red" }}>
      <Grid item xs={2}>
        <Typography variant="body1">Testing Column 1</Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={4}>
        <Typography variant="body1">Testing Column 1</Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <Typography variant="body1">Testing Column 1</Typography>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>Issue Here</Grid> //<-- Move it inside parent Grid
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</Grid>;
```

Working Example:

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Comment: Thanks for your  prompt answer, but I'm quite curious what the root cause is? Cos It also works if using normal text like P or just text only instead of typography

Comment: It's the nature of Material UI `Grid`, they try to group into small Grids and have some spaces in between them. While native HTML <p/> doesn't have that.